# Help with small error - JAVA

Tags: java, object, constructor

Hi just a quick question..

I've constructed an object clientdetailslist from Strings which have been scanned in

```
      ClientDetails clientdetailslist = new ClientDetails(client_ID,
                title, initials, surname, clientname,
                street, townorcity, postcode, clientaddress);
```

However the ClientDetails which comes after new is giving an error and I can't see why. I thought it might be a problem with the class but I'm pretty certain it's fine. Any help would be great as I really can't work out why :|

Edit : the error message is one from NetBeans reading:

> cannot find symbol symbol: constructor
>   Clientdetails(java.lang.String etc
>   etc) location class: ClientDetails

PS would of posted a pic but I don't have the rep.

Sorry if it's not enough info. If you do need more just comment and Ill get it up ASAP. Thanks

Comment: Um, would you care to share what that error is?

Comment: Please paste the error message.

Comment: Its not an error when it runs. It's an error in NetBeans.. 


cannot find symbol
symbol: constructor 
Clientdetails(java.lang.String etc etc)
location class: ClientDetails

Comment: It means there's no constructor that takes the arguments you're trying to give it. Please post your constructor code.

Comment: `ClientDetails clientdetailslist = new ClientDetails(client_ID,
                    fullName,
                    address);`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is your capitalization (since Java is case sensitive).  ClientDetails != Clientdetails

Comment: I think he wrote that part in.  I don't think it's part of the actual error.  Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is most likely in the ClientDetails class.

When creating your own class, it needs to have a constructor method, in this case it would be of the form:

```
 public ClientDetails(Parameters){
//Enter code here
}
```

That Netbeans error is a compiler error that is suggesting that ClientDetails does not have a constructor method. Therefore you are trying to call the ClientDetails constructor without the method actually existing in the ClientDetails class.

To fix this you  need access to ClientDetails to add in the constructor (or if it exists to make it public).